# ProgressBar single color gradient

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have this code for a shape (it's set as `progressDrawable` in `ProgressBar`):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="16"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="#DDD" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270">
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="16"
            android:useLevel="true">

            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/red"
                android:startColor="@color/blue"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

As it is specified, color changes throughout the circle as gradient from blue to red. For example, at maximum gradient value (100) the start is blue and at the end is red. How can I set so the color is only one? As for example, 100 value would set all circle to be red, 70 (some sort of orange), 50 (some sort of yellow) - the whole circle till the specific value must be single color, not of mixed colors. Thank you.

Comment: You want a solid color with no gradient, but the progress bar level affects the solid color? That would be done on the Kotlin side, not in the XML.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for answer. Did you mean I have to do it manually on the Kotlin side by specifying specific values and colors? Or is there a more precise approach? Thank you.

Comment: There's no way in XML to connect the progress bar's level to the value of a drawable. I haven't worked with modifying ShapeDrawable colors, but I think there must be a way to get a reference to the drawable in your code and you could add a progress bar listener that changes the color that's set on the drawable.